# Unity3D iOS Build only works on some iPads

Tags: ios, ipad, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity3D project that I am building for iOS.

It contains a lot of UI and so I have a scene dedicated to UI. This scene is loaded first and `DontDestroyOnLoad` scripts are attached to most objects in the scene.

There is also a script in the UI Scene that loads another scene on `Start`, over which the UI is displayed.

I am using Unity `5.4.1`.

The weird thing is that when I build and run the generated Xcode project it works well and as expected on an iPad Air 2, but as soon as it is put on an Air 1 it never gets past the splash screen.

On the Air 1 I get the splash screen as expected and then as the it goes to fade out it starts flickering and is never dismissed.

Has anyone come across this before or have any idea what could cause it?

EDIT: It also works fine on an iPad 4.

Comment: what's your target iOS version?  look in build settings

Comment: dude you have an iPad1?  whoa  :)

Comment: Air 1. Not 1. And it's iOS 9.

Comment: oh I beg your pardon!  :)

Comment: is your Canvas set correctly (that's "scale with screen size" - the other settings are useless)

Comment: Yes I spent a long while making sure it's all scaling and being positioned correctly. Also I've just tried it on an iPad 4 and it works fine. So far it's just the Air 1 which doesn't work. Really weird.

Comment: Interestingly the difference between the 4 and the Air 1 is the graphics API. Open GLES2 vs Metal. Am testing now.

Answer (score 1):

> SOLVED

It turns out that there is a weird bug with UI rendering using the `Metal` graphics API **ONLY** on iPad Air 1.

The way to get round this for now is to turn off Auto graphics api and delete the Metal option leaving only OpenGLES2.